# How understand data() method of boost::array, and return add length?

Tags: boost

```
boost::array<char,7>  buf = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
...
...
std::cout << buf.data() + 5;
```

It's display: fg

How to understand it?

> buf.data() + 5

Thanks

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/68-pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buf.data()` seems to return a pointer to the internal array buffer in question.

From there, standard pointer arithmetic applies, and you see the 6th character onwards in the `std::cout.operator<<` call.

Answer (score 1):

`buf.data()` is defined to return a pointer to the first element of the array, and the elements in a Boost.Array are defined to be contiguous.

So `buf.data() + 5` will be a pointer to the element (in this case, character) of the array.
You could also write `&buf[5]` and get the same pointer.

Note that in the code above:

```
std::cout << buf.data() + 5;
```

you are attempting to print the value of the pointer, not the character it points to.